# Python 2.7 type hinting callable types in PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm trying to use type hinting in python 2.7 as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

I have a function that expects a callable (a function) with a specific signature as a parameter and I can't figure out how to annotate it.

I've tried

```
def set_function(self, function):
    # type: ((int) -> None) -> None
```

But PyCharm shows an expected ')' and unexpected tokens errors

I can't seem to find any documentation for this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to document a callable within Pycharm (or within any other tool that understands [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type hints) is like so:

```
from typing import Callable

def set_function(self, function):
    # type: (Callable[[int], None]) -> None
    ...
```

Since you're using Python 2, you'll need to install the `typing` module from PyPi, if you haven't already. (`typing` was added to Python's standard library in 3.5, the module on PyPi is a backport).

You can find more information on using the typing module in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and within the documentation for [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#callable-types-and-lambdas).

(If you're not aware, mypy is a command line tool that also understands PEP 484 type hints and will also statically analyze and typecheck your code. It is an independent effort from Pycharm's built-in type checker. Since both Pycharm and mypy use PEP 484 types, mypy's documentation is often a good place to start looking to learn more about using type hints.)